# How convert uri into url for google reverse image search?

Tags: java, android, url, uri, google-image-search

Is It possible to convert an Uri (of an image on my gallery) to an Url for to use:

https://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url="IMAGE_URL"

and obtain the result of the relative google image reverse search? If not, why?

I use this code:

```
...
// get the uri of an image into the gallery
...
URL imgUrl = new URL(imgUri.toString());
...
// load the desired web page
myWebView.loadUrl("https://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url="+imgUrl);

// set the entire Activity window as a WebView
setContentView(myWebView); 
...
```

the URL that I obtain is:

file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/it.androidapp......../files/Pictures/imgCamera/photo.jpg

and the Google web page that appears is empty with the written:

"The URL does not refer to an image, or the image is not publicly accessible."

So I think that this is not a converting from uri to url problem but that this approach can not really be realized because Google reverse image search requires a url of a public image, that is, an image present on the Internet and not on a mobile device.

Is It right? Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: If you're trying to convert it to String, you can use `uri.getPath();`

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes I updated my question

Comment: Yes, you are right. Google only reverse searches url of public images on the Internet. Not on a mobile device.